# macbook pro appstore apple id is not editable

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-id

I have bought used macbook pro and now I am trying to install my applications

when I open the playstore I found the old user apple id and it is not editable, how I can remove this and add mine

[image]

Comment: the previous owner has to relinquish it to you first.

Comment: what do you mean by relinquish ?

Answer (score 1):

Any application downloaded from the App Store will have the account pre-filled like in your example. It would be best for you to complete each of these steps - most importantly the sixth step of a full erase and reinstall.

Since iWork and iLife are all free, you can re-download them once you wipe and reinstall the computer.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201065

Answer (score 0):

Tell previous owner to log in and remove this (your) device from its profile.

Then you can create your ID and log in.

[see how here.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204074)